# How to make sure a table is indexed by a certain column when using RedBean PHP ORM?

Tags: php, orm, indexing, redbean

I have an entity named 'account' which will have a username column and I want to index by this because I will be using it to lookup the username when logging in.

How do I tell redbean orm that I would like this table to have column 'username' to be indexed for faster lookup? Would I have to update the database manually instead of going through redbean orm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
R::$writer->addIndex('account','userindex','username');
```

Comment: How is it possible to add a multi-column non unique index (for which [addUniqueIndex](http://www.redbeanphp.com/api/class-RedBeanPHP.QueryWriter.html) does not work)?